# Struggling to work out how to send an embedded message to a certain channel with Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a suggestion command where it sends an embed containing the suggestion the user made so a suggestions channel. But I keep on getting errors. It sends the conformation message, but then raises this error in the console:

```py
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 473, in suggest
    await message.channel.send("Thank you, your suggestion has been tracked in <#849311393269284954>!")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 72, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'channel'
```

This is my code:

```py
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *,message):
  await message.channel.send("Thank you, your suggestion has been tracked in <#849311393269284954>!")


  channel = client.get_channel("849311393269284954")

  embedVar = discord.Embed(title="New suggestion!", description=f"`{message}`" .format(message), color=0x27db91)
  embedVar.set_footer(text="Submitted by: {}".format(message.author.display_name), icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

  await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@client.command()` is different from an `on_message` event.

`on_message` has a `discord.Message` object which has a lot of attributes. (`channel, author, guild, content, and etc`)

when you perform `message.channel.send` this is considering, you have a `discord.Message` object as message variable which has an attribute channel, so `message.channel` gets you `discord.TextChannel` object to which you then send the message to.

the `message` in your arguments, it becomes a `string (str)` input, and `NOT` a `discord.Message` object, but you have `context (ctx)` which has similar attributes too but there are more attributes than what message has. You can simply use `ctx.send("Your Message")`

Your modified code will look like:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *,message):
  await ctx.send("Thank you, your suggestion has been tracked in <#849311393269284954>!")


  channel = client.get_channel("849311393269284954") #this is an issue! Read more to find out

  embedVar = discord.Embed(title="New suggestion!", description=f"`{message}`", color=0x27db91) # why both f-string and .format()????? doesn't make sense
  embedVar.set_footer(text="Submitted by: {}".format(ctx.author.display_name), icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

  await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

The second issue you will face is, `AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute 'send'` because your `channel` variable will return as None

`get_channel` expects an `integer (int)` value, if you pass a string, it will return None

So now your code will look like this:

```
@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *,message):
  await ctx.send("Thank you, your suggestion has been tracked in <#849311393269284954>!")


  channel = client.get_channel(849311393269284954) #removed the " "

  embedVar = discord.Embed(title="New suggestion!", description=f"`{message}`", color=0x27db91) # why both f-string and .format()????? doesn't make sense
  embedVar.set_footer(text="Submitted by: {}".format(ctx.author.display_name), icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)

  await channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

Comment: Ah, that works! Thanks for the help, although the footer doesn't, throws this error: `embedVar.set_footer(text="Submitted by: {}".format(ctx.author.display_name), icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'` but for now, I'm not bothered. The main part of it works great! :D

Comment: ahh that's me, I forgot to change the `message.author.avatar_url` to `ctx.author.avatar_url`

Comment: I see, Ill try that.

Yup, it works! :D
Thanks again.